# Unable to access phpmyadmin internally and externally in redhat linux server

Tags: php, linux, apache, phpmyadmin, redhat

I installed lamp stack in redhat linux 8 server.
apache, mysql, php installed successfully.

but after installed the phpmyadmin It is unable to access internally and externally.

after curl internally I am having this error

`curl 10.64.100.224/phpMyAdmin/`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>301 Moved Permanently</title> </head><body> <h1>Moved Permanently</h1> <p>The document has moved <a href="http://10.64.100.224/phpMyAdmin/">here</a>.</p> </body></html>
```

when I tried to access it externally via browser I am having

`http://10.64.100.224/phpMyAdmin/`

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

this is phpMyAdmin.conf file

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
      Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

I am expecting to access phpMyAdmin internally and externally.

Comment: If you want to access it externally, then `Deny from All` and only `Allow from 127.0.0.1` doesn't make sense. That blocks all requests that doesn't come through 127.0.0.1 (which is the internal local IP address for the server)

Comment: And it would be useful, as you are using Apache 2.4 to change those to the Apache 2.4 syntax. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps then issue was fixed:

```bash
mkdir /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/tmp  
chmod 777 /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/tmp  
chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/phpMyAdmin  

systemctl restart httpd  

yum install -y policycoreutils-python-utils  

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/'  
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/tmp(/.*)?"  

restorecon -Rv '/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/'


firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http  
firewall-cmd --reload
```